# Segfault accessing BSS memory

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

```
section .data
    bufChar:    equ 0

section .bss
bufNum:     resb    1
bufMult:    resb    1
```

.
.
.

```
leerNumero:
    xor eax,eax
    mov [bufNum],eax
    add eax,1
    mov [bufMult],eax
inicioLeerNumero:
    mov edx,1
    mov ecx,bufChar
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,3
    int 80h
    cmp byte [ecx + edx - 1],10 ; Segfaults here.
    je  rLeerNumero
    cmp byte [ecx + edx - 1],48
    jl  noNumero
    cmp byte [ecx + edx - 1],57
    jg  noNumero
    sub eax,48
    mul word [bufMult]
    jo  overflow
    add [bufNum],eax
    jo  overflow
    mov eax,10
    mul word [bufMult]
    jo  overflow
    mov [bufMult],eax
    jmp inicioLeerNumero
rLeerNumero:
    mov eax,bufNum
    ret
noNumero:
    mov eax,errorNumero
    mov ebx,lErrorNumero
    call    imprimir
    jmp salir
overflow:
    mov eax,errorOverflow
    mov ebx,lErrorOverflow
    call    imprimir
    jmp salir
```

This code *should* of work, at least in paper it does. I need to do some homework completely in assembly without linking the C Library, hence why i am re-inventing the wheel and making a method to read a number from the console into EAX.

I am having  a mysterious segfault at the line marked with the comment and i fail to see how i coud be trying to access misaligned memory... any ideas on how could this be failing?

Comment: Use `objdump -d obj.o` to verify that `mov ecx, bufChar` does indeed load the address (and not just an offset, or the contents of the variable.)

Comment: mov ecx,bufChar is translating to mov    $0x0,%ecx.... is it really trying to mov into 0x00000000?

Comment: I have to wonder...is it actually breaking *on* the mov, or is that the instruction EIP is currently pointing at (which would seem to implicate the system call right before it)?

Comment: @Machinarius: That's GAS/AT&T syntax; the source and destination operands are backwards from how most x86 assemblers show them.  `mov $0x0, %ecx` is equivalent to `mov ecx, 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that `int 80h` is changing `ecx` or `edx` on you causing a bad pointer read?  If you can read the registers in a debugger before and after that instruction, you could confirm that.

Comment: `int 80h` "shouldn't" modify any register but `eax` (result or error). `bufChar` is not shown, so we don't know what it is. `bufNum` and `bufMult` each reserve a single byte, and you're moving `eax` (4 bytes) into them. This "probably" won't segfault, but it's wrong! Show us `bufChar`.

Comment: There are system calls that may change more registers but eax, for example: waitpid - wait for a processes to terminate. return values are: eax pid of finished process | ECHILD | EINVAL | ERESTART,  ecx exit state of finished process, if non-zero value was input in ecx.

Answer (score 0):

I had declared bufChar as .data, obviously `mov`'ing into a constant would segfault the thing. Sadly, i wasted a week wrapping my head around this, just realized so.